# Saving DropDown Value to PhpMySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I would like to know how can I save a dropdown select value to a database, I am receiving an error that says "Invalid Input: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near." By the time I implemented a Gender DropDown.

Here's the Code

```
if(empty($_POST['Gender'])){
$Gender = '';
$flag=1;
} else
$Gender = ($_POST['Gender']);
```

And the Select:

```
<select id="Gender" name="Gender" class="input-xlarge">
<option>Select Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
```

Input:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, Gender, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', $UserName', '$EPassword', '$EreEnterPassword', '$EmailAdd', '$reEnterEmailAdd'); ";
```

Comment: What does `echo $sql` show?

Comment: Try to save the NULL in $Gender = NULL; instead of $Gender = '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way your php mysql select statement is formed:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName'); ";
```

Either remove the single quotes from all variable names within double quotes.

Or use single quotes at the beginning and sorround your variables like this:

```
' . $FirstName . '
```

This will do the trick:

```
$sql = ' INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, Gender, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
VALUES ('.$FirstName.', '.$LastName.', '.$Gender.', '.$UserName.', '.$EPassword.', '.$EreEnterPassword.', '.$EmailAdd.', '.$reEnterEmailAdd.')';
```

Also look into this answer: [Single quotes or double quotes for variable concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316060/single-quotes-or-double-quotes-for-variable-concatenation)

P.S. your application is totally vulnerable to sql injection. You should look into how to sanitize user input.

Comment: "..using double quotes to define the sentence, and then you are using single quotes in the variables (for example: '$FirstName') the problem is that in this way php will not recognise $FirstName as a variable, rather it will treat it as a string"  : False. $FirstName will be recognized as a variable because you have the whole sentence in double quotes.

Comment: @ArtemideInnominato it will not recognise '$FirstName' as a variable.

Comment: @helloworld I'm having the same problem again, on another page. I don't know what's causing it.

Invalid Input: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Cruz, 0935 400 7214, brcruz@banawesports.com, Wash, Meguia Wax)' at line 2 INSERT INTO Supplier(name, cnum, email, service, prod) VALUES (Bryan Cruz, 0935 400 7214, brcruz@banawesports.com, Wash, Meguia Wax)

$sql = ' INSERT INTO Supplier(name, cnum, email, service, prod)    VALUES ('.$name.', '.$cnum.', '.$email.', '.$service.', '.$prod.')';

Comment: @googlelord could you open a question with further details about the problem. Then paste a link here so I can check it, if I can do anything I will gladly help

Comment: @googlelord maybe you could try setting the variables like this: " '. $varianlename . ' " the mysql parser may need the data to be enclosed in double quotes, let me know if that was the problem

Comment: That did save. I was reading through the link you posted. Thank you so much.

Comment: @helloworld Please read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980939/php-single-quotes-within-the-double-quote and as you can deduce reading it, the use of a php variable in a single quotes all put in a double quoted string let the php variable to be used as a string variable and not as a string.

Comment: @ArtemideInnominato looks like you are right. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use missed single quotes near $UserName,

try this

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, Gender, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', '$UserName', '$EPassword', '$EreEnterPassword', '$EmailAdd', '$reEnterEmailAdd'); ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, Gender, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', '$UserName', '$EPassword', '$EreEnterPassword', '$EmailAdd', '$reEnterEmailAdd')";
```

1) Single Quote missing Before $UserName,

2) Remove Semicolumn After Round Brace Finish,

3) Try To Use "." Concatination Operator So You Can Ger Perfect Variable Name,
Like ( ' . $FirstName . ', ' . $LastName . ', ' . $Gender . ' And So On )